# URL rewriting in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url in wordpress.
How can i rewrite my url in wordpress.
I am trying to create htaccess file like following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shopboxtile/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://localhost/shopboxtile/?productid=$1
</IfModule>
```

I think it is not correct.please help me to correct it.
My requirement is to convert url from
`http://localhost/shopboxtile/?productid=59961` to `http://localhost/shopboxtile/59961`

Comment: how come the url from and to are the same url?

Answer (score 1):

Try and put this in `.htaccess` file in `shopboxtile` folder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ ?productid=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark.I have one more problem can you please help me.I am disable wordpress rewrite using remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');.This function is working but in my application which is not involking my .htaccess file in my root directory.how can we solve this problem.please spend little of your valuable  time for me master..please

Comment: Imm, I lack knowledge of wordpress's remove_filter, may be raise new question about that `remove_filter`